# I use :after and clear :both to clean float, but I dont why the element must be block ,why not inline?

Tags: html, css

I use :after and clear :both to clean float, but I dont why the element must be block ,why not inline?

clear:both means that the element (left and right )can not be surrounding with the float element. but if the element is inline, the clear is not working ,why?
here is the code http://jsbin.com/qudujo/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Because the specification says so: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#flow-control

Answer (score 2):

By default `:after` and `:before` are inline elements (which cannot be cleared). Because you have specified the `content` property to be `""` there is essentially no width or height on the `:after` pseudo element so it will have no effect on it's parent (it basically occupies no space).
However, making it a block level element and setting the `clear` property to `both` will force it to span the full width of the parent and will clear any floated elements that come before it.

Answer (score -1):

i hope this helps: There was a style missing.

```css
.container{
  border:1px blue solid;
}
.item{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background-color:red;
  border:2px solid;
  float:left;
}
.container:after{
  content:"";

  display:block;
   
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```